# What is the expected behavior of assigning undef or '' to the %SIG hash?

Tags: perl

I tried looking up the documents but did not find anything definitive. However testing shows that it behaves the same as assigning 'DEFAULT' as a signal handler. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your testing is correct; setting a slot in `%SIG` to `undef` or `""` is  explicitly handled to be the same as `DEFAULT`:

[`else if (!sv || memEQs(s, len,"DEFAULT") || !len) {`](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/ba6e05cf4bd2843ce3e50128990edc530f65f044/mg.c#L1646)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple - this is unexpected value and that's why it's undocumented.

Why are you trying to assign something for which the behavior is undefined although there's a list of supported values for all you need? Although it may work somehow in current version, it may easily change in future and your program will stop working...

Comment: In a function I wrote that needs to handle some signals thus has its own signal handlers, I'm trying to restore the original signal handlers before exiting a function. I am not using "local" because of some scoping issues. When I read in the values from the original SIG hash, some of them were undefined. I will follow your suggestion and assign them with 'DEFAULT' if the stored version is undefined.

Comment: Well, 'DEFAULT' will restore default OS signal handler. If I understand correctly, you want to restore original handlers when the function was called. Although I don't understand the issue with using `local`, reassigned previously read value should be fine (as no matter what it is it should be consistent for both reads and writes).

Comment: In my case the previously read value could be undefined. Thank you!

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000 `local` only works if you want to alter a value in a single dynamic scope. Sometimes that's not possible; e.g. sometimes you're temporarily changing it at one time, to put it back later on. E.g. consider `my $oldsig;  sub setup { $oldsig = $SIG{TERM}; }  sub teardown { $SIG{TERM} = $oldsig; }`. This assigns `undef` if it's not careful.